# how to launch ec2 instance using AWS SDK and connect to it via AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-cli

this is a newbie question. Please, bear with me.

I tried to create an instance using AWS SDK for JAVA by following the official tutorial. When It comes to the key pair part I get confused :

```
 CreateKeyPairRequest createKeyPairRequest = new CreateKeyPairRequest();
    createKeyPairRequest.withKeyName("azzouz_key");
    CreateKeyPairResult createKeyPairResult = Client.createKeyPair(createKeyPairRequest);
    KeyPair keyPair = new KeyPair();
    keyPair = createKeyPairResult.getKeyPair();
    String privateKey = keyPair.getKeyMaterial();

    RunInstancesRequest runInstancesRequest = new RunInstancesRequest();

    runInstancesRequest.withImageId("ami-4b814f22")
            .withInstanceType("m1.small")
            .withMinCount(1)
            .withMaxCount(1)
            .withKeyName("azzouz_key")
            .withSecurityGroups("Azzouz_group");
```

By doing like this, how can I use aws cli to connect to the instance I created using the SDK, I mean how to locate the .pem file ( if it does exist ). Is my logic correct in term of creating ec2 instance using the code and manage it via aws cli, or it should all be in the same way?!

Answer (score 2):

The PEM key is in the contents of your `privateKey` String variable. You need to write that out to a file, as this is the only time you will be able to get to it via the API.

To connect to the server, you don't use the AWS CLI. You would use the `ssh` command. I would read the answers to this question for more information about using SSH to connect to an EC2 server: [how to login to ec2 machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918343/how-to-login-to-ec2-machine)

Comment: Thank you. I know that I have to use ssh command, that's what I meant.
So the solution is writing the privateKey to a file. Gonna try this and let you know if it helped.

Comment: You specified "AWS CLI" in your question, which is the name of a specific tool AWS provides. https://aws.amazon.com/cli/